# how to convert string number (on a dataset) to numeric values using the program R?

Tags: r

I tried to search for the data but I could not any sources that knew the answer.

This is the data that I tried

```
nutritionData$group1 <- 0 
nutritionData$group1[nutritionData$heart_disease > == yes] <- 1
```

Comment: Try changing your second line to: `nutritionData$group1[nutritionData$heart_disease  == "yes"] <- 1`

Comment: What are you trying to do with `nutritionData$heart_disease > == yes` ? Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Also show expected output for the data shared. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).